# Entity Framework Update to Scalar Foreign Key Not Updating Value Of Navigation Property

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework-core, blazor

I have a project that update a class called requisition line item, which has a relationship with a status class.  Whenever I update the StatusId field in the requisition line item and then pull the list again, I get the right data for the new StatusId but the Status object that is the navigational property, doesn't update to reflect that despite it being a new query.

Here is my injection:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDataService, DataService>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("PrimaryDatabaseConnection")));
```

Here is my data context:

```
public partial class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Requisition> RequisitionData { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RequisitionLineItem> RequisitionLineItemData { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Status> StatusData { get; set; }

    public DataContext()
    {

    }

    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Requisition>().HasMany<RequisitionLineItem>(x => x.RequisitionLineItems).WithOne(x=>x.Requisition).HasPrincipalKey(x=>x.Id).HasForeignKey(x=>x.RequisitionId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<RequisitionLineItem>().HasOne<Status>(x => x.Status);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Requisition>().HasOne<Status>(x => x.Status);


        modelBuilder.Entity<RequisitionLineItem>().Ignore(x => x.TotalCost);
        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);

   
}
```

Here is my classes

```
[Table("RequisitionLineItems")]
public partial class RequisitionLineItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Requisition")]
    public int RequisitionId { get; set; }
    public Requisition Requisition { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Status")]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public int PartNumber { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal CostPerItem { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public decimal TotalCost { get {  return CostPerItem * Quantity; } }
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public string? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

```
[Table("Statuses")]
public partial class Status
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool LineItemStatus { get; set; }
}
```

I update like this:

```
requisitionLineItem.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
requisitionLineItem.ModifiedBy = currentUserAD;
var originalRequisitionLineItem = _context.RequisitionLineItemData.Find(requisitionLineItem.Id);
if (originalRequisitionLineItem != null)
{
    _context.Entry(originalRequisitionLineItem).State = EntityState.Detached;
    _context.Entry(requisitionLineItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

and get a new list of items in a method like this

```
//this return the list with the right Id but the old Status object
RequisitionList = DataService.GetRequisitions();
//if i recreate a new context like this it works fine though.  The database has the right data
DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext> optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("fakestringforstack");
var testCotnext = new DataContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
var testService = new DataService(testCotnext);
var reqs = testService.GetRequisitions();
```

In summary, my problem seems to be that unless I refresh the page entirely or create a new context instead of using the one I injected, the navigation property never gets updated.